# Varolz, the Scar-Striped rulings with double-faced/flip cards

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

[Varolz, the Scar-Striped](http://forums.mtgsalvation.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=141221&d=1365653080) says

> Each creature card in you graveyard has scavenge. Their scavenge cost is equal to its mana cost.

My question is simple: do I get to choose which side I can scavenge?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is simple: No. You must choose the card's front face (the face which has the sun symbol in the top-left corner.) In the case of flip cards, you must choose the card's normal characteristics.

[Rule reference:](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules)

> 711.2a In every zone other than the battlefield, and also on the battlefield with its front face up, a double-faced card has only the characteristics of the front face.
>
> 709.2. In every zone other than the battlefield, and also on the battlefield before the permanent flips, a flip card has only the normal characteristics of the card. Once a permanent is flipped, its normal name, text box, type line, power, and toughness don't apply and the alternative versions of those characteristics apply instead.

Comment: on the plus side, you can scavenge death's shadow and phyrexian dreadnaught to get 13 or 12 respective +1/+1 counters for only 1 mana!